# How to use the rest api without body data

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, rest-api

I have rest API URL but how to run the in rest API.

```
    $service_url='http://testing.com/data/rest/Masters/CheckPartnerId?Key=121&Type=CREATE&PartnerId=13&BrandId=67&StoreId=main_website_store&ValidateId=Mpnid&UserName=anurag.111@gmail.com';

 try {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
           // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            $response1 = json_decode($response, true);
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($response1); exit;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            //$debugshipData['result'] = array('error' => $e->getMessage(), 'code' => $e->getCode());
        }
```

Can you please help me

Comment: why are you commenting the $CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS? that is the line supposed to send the data in the POST variable... what is the problem?

Comment: So, is it solved in this way? then i will put my comment as answer and you could mark it as accepted to help out others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working.

```
$service_url='http://testing.com/data/rest/Masters/CheckPartnerId?Key=121&Type=CREATE&PartnerId=13&BrandId=67&StoreId=main_website_store&ValidateId=Mpnid&UserName=anurag.111@gmail.com';

     try {
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
                $response = curl_exec($ch);

                $response1 = json_decode($response, true);
                echo '<pre>'; print_r($response1); exit;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                //$debugshipData['result'] = array('error' => $e->getMessage(), 'code' => $e->getCode());
            }
```